# Can't Save or Create a wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add an existing page to an existing menu. When I click "Save & Publish" not working in main menu. please help me guys...

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding from Appearance -> Menu
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are adding your menu to right desired menu Main Menu in your case .... for that select Main Menu from menu selection.

Comment: but when i click the menu its shows 500 internal server error. how can i fix this issue